# ¿Como puedo mover un listado de un boton dropdown?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Quiero mover el listado de un dropdown para que quede centrado ó ala izquierda pero no se como
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo quieres alineado a la izquierda _no me queda claro ya que dices centrado a la izquierda_, intenta con `text-align: left`, si no obtienes el resultado que esperas, agrega tu código para tratar de replicarlo, así es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: perdon falto una o

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo con bootstrap o con css?

Comment: Quisiera implementarlo con Css

Comment: Hola Julián, puedes poner el código completo? HTML, CSS y JS si lo usas. Con eso te podremos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

En tu CSS puedes cambiar el flujo del elemento con `Position:relative`, de esta forma podrás utilizar los atributos `Top, Left, Right y Bottom`.

Dándole un `Top` puedes mover el elemento los Pixeles que necesites hacia abajo.

Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: por favor no mandes saludos en tu respuesta, no es bien visto en la comunidad y tampoco es necesario

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo en tu screenshot parece que usas Bootstrap.
Si es así y usas la versión 4.0 la solución es añadir la clase `dropdown-menu-right`.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Right-aligned menu
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Documentación Bootstrap 3.0](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/components/#dropdowns-alignment)

[Documentación Bootstrap 4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)